# Get error when running ionic live reload on wifi adb

Tags: ionic-framework, adb, wifi

I am trying to work trough wifi adb. So i connected my device with wifi and the regular ionic build works fine.

But when i trying to build with live reload ->  ionic cordova run android -l

I got error:

```
[native-run] Error: Command failed: C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb -s 192.###.###.###:5555 reverse tcp:8101 tcp:8101
[native-run] adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator
[native-run]
[native-run] at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
[native-run] at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
[native-run] at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
[native-run] at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution here: https://github.com/ionic-team/native-run/issues/28

ionic cordova run android --host=0.0.0.0 --public-host= --port 8100 --livereload --no-native-run